# Node.js app works on Local host but giving 404 Error on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am new to Heroku and Node.js. It works fine on the localhost but giving this error on Heroku.

> 404 Not Found

I am stuck in this problem for a week. I searched on the internet but can not find a working solution. I also added Config Vars in Heroku under settings. In my client React app I am calling this "https://work.herokuapp.com/events/daily" API to get data. 
my server full code:

```
const express = require('express');
const pg = require('pg');

const app = express();
require('dotenv').config();

const pool = new pg.Pool();

const queryHandler = (req, res, next) => {
  pool.query(req.sqlQuery).then((r) => {
    return res.json(r.rows || [])
  }).catch(next)
}

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.send('Welcome  ');
})

app.get('/events/hourly', (req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  req.sqlQuery = `
    SELECT date, hour, events
    FROM public.hourly_events
    ORDER BY date, hour
    LIMIT 50;
  `
  return next()
}, queryHandler)

app.get('/events/daily', (req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  req.sqlQuery = `
    SELECT date, SUM(events) AS events
    FROM public.hourly_events
    GROUP BY date
    ORDER BY date
    LIMIT 7;
  `
  return next()
}, queryHandler)

app.get('/stats/hourly', (req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  req.sqlQuery = `
    SELECT poi_id, date, hour, impressions, clicks, revenue
    FROM public.hourly_stats
    ORDER BY date, hour
    LIMIT 168;
  `
  return next()
}, queryHandler)

app.get('/stats/daily', (req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  req.sqlQuery = `
    SELECT date,
        SUM(impressions) AS impressions,
        SUM(clicks) AS clicks,
        SUM(revenue) AS revenue
    FROM public.hourly_stats
    GROUP BY date
    ORDER BY date
    LIMIT 10;
  `
  return next()
}, queryHandler)

app.get('/poi', (req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  req.sqlQuery = `
  SELECT *
  FROM public.poi;
  `
  return next()
}, queryHandler)

app.get('/join/poi/stats_hourly', (req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  req.sqlQuery = `
  SELECT DISTINCT *
  FROM public.poi, public.hourly_stats
  WHERE public.poi.poi_id = public.hourly_stats.poi_id
  LIMIT 10;
  `
  return next()
}, queryHandler)

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5555, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err)
    process.exit(1)
  } else {
    console.log(`Running on ${process.env.PORT || 5555}`)
  }
})

// last resorts
process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
  console.log(`Caught exception: ${err}`)
  process.exit(1)
})
process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
  console.log('Unhandled Rejection at: Promise', p, 'reason:', reason)
  process.exit(1)
})
```

Comment: a 404 usually means the server cant find what you are requesting for. So your server is up and running but can't get the resource you are requesting. May be more context will be helpful to solve your problem

Comment: I added my server full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Heroku, under "More" on the top right when in your application's dashboard, you can "View Logs" to see if it is spinning up properly and if you're getting any errors.

Make sure to setup a Procfile, which tells Heroku what to actually run on the dynos.

The syntax is easy:

```
dyno_name_here: cli_command_here
```

Comment: I added the Procfile file and checked logs. Getting this error 'Error injecting runtime env: bundle not found '/app/build/static/js/*.js'. See: https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack/blob/master/README.md#user-content-custom-bundle-location
'    Don't know how to solve. Please help